# Solving mixed trigonometric polynomial equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have the following equation (along with some other equations which are not relevant here):

$$\mu \sin(x) \sin(\mu\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=x\sin(\mu\frac{\pi}{2})$$

where $1<\mu<2$ and $0<x<\mu\frac{\pi}{2}$.

It can be also expressed as:

$$\sin(\mu\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\frac{\sin(\mu\frac{\pi}{2})}{\mu\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$$

Graphically I can see that it has exactly one root for $x$ if the value of $\mu$ is fixed.

Is there any hope that $x$ can be expressed as a function of $\mu$, or maybe $\mu$ as a function of $x$ with analytical methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the product-to-sum formula, we rewrite

$$\frac\mu2\cos\frac{\mu\pi}2-\frac\mu2\cos\frac{4x-\mu\pi}2=x\sin\frac{\mu\pi}2.$$

By a linear change of variable, this is of the form

$$\cos t=a(\mu)t+b(\mu)$$ and there is no hope of an analytical form. (Anyway the geometric interpretation is easy: a cosinusoid intercepted by a straight line.)

The $(x,\mu)$ relation won't be analytical either because of $\mu$ both inside and outside of the trigonometric functions. (Even the simpler $\text{sinc }\mu=x$ wouldn't be invertible.)